# How to use partials inside markdown?

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'm just starting out with Hakyll and am working with the default site that comes with `hakyll init`. I tried putting the following in `2015-08-12.spqr.markdown`:

```
$partial("includes/DB.hs")$
```

It didn't work as expected - the post just showed the literal text `$partial("includes/DB.hs")$`. It didn't pull in the content of `includes/DB.hs` into the post. Then I tried adding the following to `site.hs`, but even this didn't work:

```
match "includes/*" $ compile templateBodyCompiler
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Partials are only recognised inside templates. You would need to compile the posts with [`templateCompiler`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2016-11-19/hakyll-4.9.1.0/Hakyll-Web-Template.html#v:templateCompiler) or by using [`applyAsTemplate`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2016-11-19/hakyll-4.9.1.0/Hakyll-Web-Template.html#v:applyAsTemplate). You can see it in the example’s [`index.html` compilation](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/blob/32e34f435c7911f36acdf4a62eec1f56faf0b269/data/example/site.hs#L55).

`applyAsTemplate` is especially useful when you also want to transform the text some more, for example to process markdown:

```
compile $ do
    getResourceString
        >>= applyAsTemplate someContext -- e.g. defaultContext
        >>= renderPandoc
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" indexCtx
        >>= relativizeUrls
```